# Display PowerPoint Slides In Windows Form vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am new to vb.net and came across an ask wherein I have to display MS Office PowerPoint slides within the form. The form must have navigation option too for navigating slides.

I've wasted almost 11 hours on google and YouTube but no joy :(

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Regards

Comment: Can you not load the PowerPoint file into a `WebBrowser` control, just as you would in IE?

Answer (score 2):

Add a `WebBrowser` control to your window/Form(or add it from code-behind) and use the `Navigate` method to display/open Office Documents such as PowerPoint Presentation(.ppt):

```
  MyWebBrowser1.Navigate(FilePathHere)
```